# Powerapp Custom Connector for Azure AD protected ASP.Net Core WebAPI - getting Unauthorized 401

Tags: asp.net-core, powerapps

I'm trying to create an MS Powerapp Custom Connector to access an ASP.NET core WebAPI, which is protected by Azure AD using the `Microsoft.Identity.Web` package. But no matter how I try to set things up, I'm always getting a 401 when trying to access the API via the connector.

So my setup looks like this:

## Azure App registrations

I have registered two apps in `Azure App Registrations`. One for the API and one for the Powerapp Connector.

For the API registration I only configured settings under 'Expose an API'. I set an Application ID URI

`api://f9****ca-****-****-****-3d30e9e*****`

and added a scope

`api://f9****ca-****-****-****-3d30e9e*****/Employees.Read.All`

I also added an authorized client application using the ID of the App registration for the Powerapp (config below).

The app registration for the Powerapp is configured as follows:

For authentication the `Web` platform is added with redirect URI of `https://global.consent.azure-apim.net/redirect`.

Under 'Certificates & secrets' I added a client secret.

Under 'Api permissions' I added a permission for the scope of the API `api://f9****ca-****-****-****-3d30e9e*****/Employees.Read.All` as `Delegated` permission.

## Powerapp Custom Connector config

The security tab of my custom connector is configured as follows:

| Setting | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Auth type | OAuth 2.0 |
| Identity Provider | Azure Active Directory |
| Client id | `<Client ID of App reg for Powerapp>` |
| Client Secret | `<Client secret of App reg for Powerapp>` |
| Login URL | https://login.windows.net |
| Tenant ID | `<AAD Tenant ID>` |
| Resource URL | `api://f9****ca-****-****-****-3d30e9e*****` `<Application ID URI of App reg for API>` |
| Scope | `api://f9****ca-****-****-****-3d30e9e*****/Employees.Read.All` |

## ASP.net core (3.1) Web App

I'm using the `Microsoft.Identity.Web` nuget package.

In my app config I added the following:

```
"AzureAd": {
"Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
"ClientId": "<Client ID of app reg for API>",
"TenantId": "<Tenant ID>"
}
```

The startup class looks like this:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApiAuthentication(Configuration);
        services.AddControllers();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
}
```

My controller is just decorated with the `[Authorize]` attribute.

Now, when I try to test an operation on the custom connector the WebAPI allways returns a `401 Unauthorized` and I can't for the life of me figure out why.

I get see, that the request header has a `Bearer token` for the user I'm using to create the connection.
So a token is issued, but somehow the WebApi deems it invalid.

Interestingly the audience in that token is `https://apihub.azure.com`. Shouldn't it be the client id of the app reg? Anyway, even if I add that audience to the valid audiences in my WebAPI, I still get the `401`...

Is there anything I am missing here? Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add the Authenction middleware.

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

Comment: Dude! I seriously cannot believe that this was it... I spend the whole day yesterday fiddling around with app registrations and what have you. I even came accross that `app.UseAuthentication()` line but dismissed it without trying - thinking 'Naa, that can't be it'. Could have saved myself a whole day by just typing these few lines. I guess I thought since I started from a project template that that would have already been in there if it was neccessary...  If you excuse me now, I'm going to hit me self a little.